# How to convert pepsin into powder form?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry, purification

I have pepsin powder which is now hydrated due to humidity. I want to convert it back to the powder form. How to do it?

I don't have access to a freeze-dryer .
I prefer any cheap procedure other than freeze-dryer .

Comment: What is "cheap"? A lab scale vacuum tray dryer is probably ~1,000 USD cheaper than a lab scale freeze dryer.

Comment: An old paper: https://doi.org/10.1021/ac60329a047 describes the cheap way of dehydrating serum. I guess that the low temperature, achieved with dry ice in acetone, prevents denaturation as the solvent is removed. The rest can apparently be done in a vacuum desiccator. As your sample is not solvated, but just wet, I would try the method on a small amount and check if reactivity is preserved

Comment: Try using a desiccator with a desiccant such as CaCl2 (cheap) or another -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_desiccants.

Comment: I accidently add some water in it... 20ml water in 100gm pepsin powder...

Comment: Do you need it for its enzymatic property or as nutrient?

Comment: as enzymatic property...